# Librosa Waveplot Displaying Wrong Time on X-Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa

I'm trying to visualize a waveplot as follows:

```
sig, rate = librosa.load(test_audio, sr=32000, offset=None)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
librosa.display.waveplot(sig, sr=3200)
```

which provides this result:

[image: waveplot]

If you look at this x-axis it makes this appear as an 8 minute audio file but it is actually only 47 seconds long. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `x-axis` is in `samples`.  By default the method downsamples the signal that means that to align another time series patron needs to compute its `x` positions in `samples` and then adjust these by the `downsampling factor` (by default `1000 / sr`).

Let me show you example, may be that will clear your doubts.

```py
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.util.example_audio_file())

tempo, beats = librosa.beat.beat_track(y=y, sr=sr, units='time', trim=False)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
librosa.display.waveplot(y=y, sr=sr)
plt.vlines(beats, -1, 1, color='r',linestyles="dashed")
plt.grid()
```

[image]

You can see that now, all displays are in natural coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The `librosa.display.waveplot` function uses the sampling rate (sr) to calculate the duration (X-axis is time by default).
This parameter should be the same in the loading function and display.
In `librosa.load` function you set sampling rate to **32 000**, but in librosa.dispaly.waveplot to **3 200**.
That is why the plotted signal is 10 times longer than expected.